# How can I fix this broken motorcycle mirror mount?

Tags: motorcycle, mirrors, wing-mirrors

My mirror screws into a small piece of metal which has broken off.

It looks like it has been broken off and welded back on before.

[image: Broken mirror mount]

[image: Broken mirror mount]

[image: Broken mirror mount]

I want to use something like this to make a new mounting hole for the mirror, but I won't be able to put it on because this metal is in the way. Does the piece of metal that is there look like it can be hammered off? Or is it welded on too strongly?

[image: Mirror mount attachment]

Otherwise, how can I fix it? Do I have to have it welded on again?

Comment: Should be easy enough to remove all of the old bracket with an angle grinder.

Answer (score 2):

If say you removed the handlebars it would give you much better access to the area to work. Once the bars are removed along with the throttle grip, I would possibly try a mini hacksaw to remove the bulk of that old braket/weld, then VERY carefully grind away the old bracket.

I say VERY carefully as you don't want to damage or remove material from the handlebar itself, as a lot of stress is put into that area when accelerating and braking.

IF you manage to damage or bite into the handlebar material, I would just get a new handlebar, they're not too expensive and it will be far safer than using a worn or damaged bar, plus your new mirror brackets will fit far easier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked how much a generic brake cylinder-lever-tank would cost locally for your bike(handlebar diameter) - with a new holder for the mirror? You might be surprised. I would just buy a generic (chinese) replacement for the whole part, can't be worse than that madmaxed piece of kit.